# Change elements from a string

Tags: python

Here's the deal, I want to change the last letter of a string to its first letter, and switch the first with the last. But when I print it, it only changes the last element. Why did this happen?

```py
mystring = 'ferrocarril'
first = mystring[0]
last = mystring[-1]
mystring = mystring.replace(mystring[0],last)
mystring = mystring.replace(mystring[-1],first)
print(mystring)
```

I expect 'lerrocarrif', but the actual output is 'ferrocarrif'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is executed one line at a time.

First, `mystring = mystring.replace(mystring[0],last)` changes the first (or rather *all*) `'f'` with `'l'`.

It has the same effect as `mystring.replace('f','l')` would have, since you assigned `'l'` to `last` and `mystring` still starts with an `'f'` at this point.

At this point, `mystring` is `'lerrocarril'`

Then `mystring = mystring.replace(mystring[-1],first)` replaces *all* `'l'` with `'f'`, resulting in what you're getting.

One way of doing what you want is:

```
mystring = 'ferrocarril'
mystring = mystring[-1] + mystring[1:-1] + mystring[0]
```

Comment: It suppose that I can´t only say thanks, but I really appreciate your answer, I didn´t know that

Comment: Even though your question may not be the most complicated, you wrote it in a correct and clear way and others like you may have similar issues - once it makes sense, it makes perfect sense :). Please accept the answer if you feel it has answered your question.

Comment: as you suppose, I'm beginner in python, again thank you for answer my question, I'm just only waiting for stack overflow allows me to accept the question